# Populate input data with result from API nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3, vue-script-setup

I have a nuxt 3 app that fetches data from the API. I would like to use that data to populate the input fields in the template but I keep getting an error.

Here is a snippet of my code

```html
<script setup>

const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const route = useRoute();

const router = useRouter();

const { data: pkg } = useFetch(
  () => '/api/id/1/'
);

const request = ref({
  field: pkg.value.field_value,
});
```

When I `console.log(pkg.value.field_value)` I get the value printed on the browser developer tools console tab but on hard refresh, I get the error `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'field_value')`

The reason why I need to dynamically set the value of field is so that I am able to update it.

Anyone encountered that problem before and how did you address it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `await` to the `useFetch` function because at the first rendering the `pkg` is not available :

```html
<script setup>

const config = useRuntimeConfig();

const route = useRoute();

const router = useRouter();

const { data: pkg } = await useFetch(
  () => '/api/id/1/'
);

const request = ref({
  field: pkg.value.field_value,
});
```